# How to use a variable mapping a json

Tags: marketing-cloud, json, ssjs

I need search the assets types in a json but mapping I have a block key that is different in all blocks.
I set a variable that cointains this values but when I want to use do not retrive the things after this block key.
This is the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.items.length; i++) {
  var email = jsonResponse.items[i];
  var emailName = email.name;
  var block = jsonResponse.items[i].views.html.slots.banner.blocks;
  var blockKeys = [];
  var asset = jsonResponse.items[i].views.html.slots.banner.blocks.blockKeys.assetType;
  var assetName = asset.name
    
   for (var blockKey in block) {
       blockKeys.push(blockKey);
      } 
    Write("\n\Name: " + emailName);
    Write("\n\Blocks: " +(blockKeys));
    Write("\n\Asset Name: " + assetName);
```

And this is the response

```
Name: Test Email Dinamico
Blocks: hmjsixa2nda,74tda2do8en
Asset Name: undefined
```

Someone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that `jsonResponse.items[i].views.html.slots.banner.blocks.blockKeys.assetType.name` is undefined in the JSON response.

If you can provide a sample JSON response, we could confirm this.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I resolved in this way

 `for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.items.length; i++) {
  var email = jsonResponse.items[i];
  var emailName = email.name;
  var block = jsonResponse.items[i].views.html.slots.banner.blocks;
  var blockKeys = [];
  for (var blockKey in block) {
       blockKeys.push(blockKey);
   
  var asset = jsonResponse.items[i].views.html.slots.banner.blocks[blockKey];
  var assetName = asset.assetType.name;`

I was using in bad way de array with de blocksKeys